# Select Numeric Values From String Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have records that have a `string` property called `Project`. The values these normally have are like A-A-40019-0 but in reality they could be anything.

I need to be able to extract the numeric values from the `Project` project property so that I can then try and cast it to a `ulong` so that it can be sorted by.

I'm trying the following code to select the number values from the `Project` property.

```
return jobs.Select(x => new JobViewModel
{         
     Sequence = x.Project.Where(y => char.IsDigit(y)).ToString()
});
```

When I try this I get the following error

> DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection
> ResultType.

I need to use Linq to Entities as I can't afford to load all records into memory.

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Bring back the `Project` property then extract the number on the client side - did you want to ignore the `-` in `A-A-40019-0` to get `400190` or just get `40019`? Does `JobViewModel` have other properties being set?

Comment: @NetMage I cant bring it to client side because I need to be able to sort by it

Comment: You can (must) sort on the client side as well. Depending on which EF you are using, you could also create a SQL Stored Procedure to extract the digits - how would you do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which DB you are using but I did find this for SQL Server. [https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/extract-numbers-from-string#:~:text=%20Extract%20Numbers%20From%20String%20In%20SQL%20Server,you%20want%20to%20split%20this%20delimited...%20More%20](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/extract-numbers-from-string#:%7E:text=%20Extract%20Numbers%20From%20String%20In%20SQL%20Server,you%20want%20to%20split%20this%20delimited...%20More%20)

Hopefully similar technique can be used for the DB you are using.

You could make a view with a column calling that function added on the end and then you can sort it.

or purely in C# which I haven't tried:

```
Convert.ToInt32(new string(y.project.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

Comment: I need to do this in C# not SQL.

Comment: You said you can't afford to load all records in memory. If you do this in C# than AFAIK the SQL will grab all the records, load them into memory run through your method and than sort it.

In any case it won't be hard to convert that SQL code to C# so give it a go. You could use a regular expression maybe to extract all the numbers out? There's plenty on Stackoverflow on how to do that.

Comment: I said I need to keep it as Linq to Entities so Regular Expressions will not work.